# ¿Cómo puedo hacer responsivo un modal, para una dataTable?

Tags: jquery, html5, datatables, bootstrap-4

Resulta que tengo un modal que muestra una tabla , pero la tabla de `dataTable` se pasa hacia la derecha y no se mantiene dentro del modal .Pongo un ejemplo delo que hice.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

 <div class="modal fade" id="compromisos" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Compromisos</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table id="compromiso_ejecutivo" class="display nowrap">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#compromisos > .modal-body').css({width:'auto',height:'auto', 'max-height':'100%'});
                        $("#compromiso_ejecutivo").dataTable();
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#compromisos">
 Mostrar
</button>
```

Eso es lo que he intentado hacer pero no se como hacer para que el contenido quede responsivo, ni siquiera con la clase `lg` del modal queda bien , ademas las columnas pueden variar mas adelante.

> NOTA: Uso bootstap 4 y jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

 <div class="modal fade" id="compromisos" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Compromisos</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table id="compromiso_ejecutivo" class="display nowrap table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                              <th>No hay columnas</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#compromisos > .modal-body').css({width:'auto',height:'auto', 'max-height':'100%'});
                        $("#compromiso_ejecutivo").dataTable();
                    });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#compromisos">
 Mostrar
</button>
```

Colocale la clase table-responsive de bootstrap

```
<table id="compromiso_ejecutivo" class="display nowrap table-responsive">
```

y asi se va adaptar al tamaño del modal la tabla

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que te está aplicando este estilo al modal:

```
@media (min-width: 576px)
.modal-dialog {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 1.75rem auto;
}
```

Y te está limitando a 500px la anchura.

Tienes la clase modal-lg para mayor tamaño:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-lg {
    max-width: 800px;
  }
}
```

Y como en este caso no sería suficiente lo mejor sería sobre-escribirla:

```
.modal-lg {
    max-width: 80% !important;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/x979n2o0/)

También tienes la opción de modificar la anchura al valor deseado en el evento `show`:

```
 $('#compromisos').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
   $(this).find('.modal-dialog').css({
   'max-width':'80%'
   });
 });
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/x979n2o0/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder , voy a  mejorarlo con las dos respuesta